# Unity UI Text position

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, canvas

I'm trying to learn Unity UI element position. But when i am trying to get UI text position with this code `Debug.Log (UI_Text.transform.position);` , i am getting high point like this **(6846.1, 29931.3, 10.0)**. In my code i attached **UI text** as Gameobject with *UI_Text* name. Also i can get UI element's screen and world point with this two code:

```
Debug.Log (Camera.main.WorldToScreen(UI_Text.transform.position));
Debug.Log (Camera.main.ScreenToWorld(UI_Text.transform.position));
```

This 2 codes working right, gives scene and world points and i understand these.
But i do not know how to work this code `Debug.Log (UI_Text.transform.position);` and what is this position **(6846.1, 29931.3, 10.0)**. How can i get this position from camera like this **Camera.main.Something**?
This is my [Canvas inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHLNo.png)
And here is [UI text inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Riq7.png)

Comment: When you look in the scene view, you can see the canvas is a large rectangle, so the positions you get are in world position based on that rectangle. It does not necessarily make sense to use the world position (sometimes though), usually, you use a mix of anchor position and sizeDelta position. You could tell more about what you want to achieve so it is easier to understand.

Comment: @Everts i am converting mouse position to world position with Camera.main.ScreenToWorld and i equate GameObject's position to that position. But it is not working with UI elements

Comment: Where in world coordinates do you have your UI canvas? Is it placed somewhere odd or do you have it around 0,0,0?

Comment: @RonBeyer My canvas's world position is (484.5, 284.0, 0.0). I guess this is default position because i can not change it

Comment: Is your canvas render mode in screen space overlay or world space?  If you want to create something stationary on the screen, such as a HUD, you would use screen space overlay.  If you want to display something in the world itself, such as a floating health bar over an enemy, you would use world space.  Also, it might help if you were to provide a screenshot of your hierarchy and inspector (with the canvas selected), as well as some context regarding what the player will be doing in this scenario.

Comment: @AlexMyers i added inspectors images

Comment: @AlexMyers i understand but if i convert to world space everything will collapse. How can i get my target on screen space?

Comment: Can you show the scene hierarchy? Is the button a direct child of the canvas?

Answer (score 1):

you can change RENDER MODE to space world - camera.
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxSrq.png)

after this set main camera to RENDER CAMERA.
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZsYv.png)

this mode perfect for 2d game .